# implementation of MVC in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, user-interface, servlets, model-view-controller

I have a form which collects user input. Then a servlet collects all the request parameters and stores it to the database. As per MVC I should have passed it to a bean and the bean should have updated the database. Is it bad programming?
Also I have to parameters "title" and "source URL". I want the title to embed the source URL.

Comment: In a web page we generally have menus and sections from which we can redirct to different part of the app. But how do I create a page which has something like "related"(bottom right of the page) what we have in stackoverflow page. Say user inputs a title, description and few more details which is stored in  db. This post by the user should be visible to all the members.

I want to implement in such a way, so that the title becomes a part of the URL as request parameter. Also if the source is an external source, the title should embed the URL.What would be the best and scalable way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

The JSP is your view, and the Servlet is your controller.

To have full MVC, there should be another Java class who's job is simply to represent the objects being stored; that's the model.  Or it may be more than one class, if the form takes multiple objects, depending on your data model.

If you're writing SQL directly into a Servlet, that's not great code; any changes you ever make to your database will require a painful update to many of your Servlets.  The idea of pulling the data model code away into another class lets you make changes to the data and database without having to edit *everything* you write.

So, if you're writing a really simple app, this is likely fine.  If you're writing something complex, this is fine for a prototype, but you'll want a stricter MVC implementation if it's something you'll have to build, maintain, and own for any length of time.

Comment: In a web page we generally have menus and sections from which we can redirct to different part of the app. But how do I create a page which has something like "related"(bottom right of the page) what we have in stackoverflow page.Say user inputs a title, description and few more details which is stored in  db. This post by the user should be visible to all the members.

I want to implement in such a way, so that the title becomes a part of the URL as request parameter. Also if the source is an external source, the title should embed the URL.What would be the best and scalable way to do it?